# Сочетание клавиш Visual Studio Code для выделение тегов

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

Как в редакторе кода Visual Studio Code, может называться сочетание клавиш которое выделяет html теги по иерархии вложенности?

Comment: выделяет html теги по иерархии вложенности - это как?

Comment: теги вложены друг в друга. я встаю курсором в самы последний тег. нажимаю , забыл , было раньше ctrl+shift+a, идет выделение тега, нажимаешь еще раз выделяется вместе с ним выше уровнем и так далее

Comment: это какой-то плагин. не было в vscode такого

Comment: было всегда, я переопределял стандартные клавиши.  не помню как назывется